# Why is the position of my object different from the field of object?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am writing a field of view method that is learned by Code Monkey. The field of view is made by mesh and I am designing the mesh. If my object (human) moves, the start of the field of view moves faster than object.

[this is mistake happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D51DZ.png)

[this is the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MLke.png)

this is the script of field of view.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyField : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MeshFilter _meshFilter;
    public float ViewAngle;
    public float ViewDistance;
    public int RayCount;
    private Mesh _mesh;
    private Vector3 _origin;
    public LayerMask LayerMask;
    private Transform _father;
    private void Awake()
    {
        _meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        _father = transform.parent;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _mesh = new Mesh();
        _meshFilter.mesh = _mesh;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        _origin = _father.position;
        float angle = ViewAngle;
        float AngleDecrease = ViewAngle / RayCount;
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[RayCount + 2];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        int[] triangles = new int[3 * RayCount];
        vertices[0]=_origin;
        int triangleIndex = 0;
        Debug.Log(_origin);
        //draw mesh
        for (int i = 1; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 dir = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)), Mathf.Sin(angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)),0);
            RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(_origin, dir, ViewDistance, LayerMask);
            Vector3 vertice;
            if (raycastHit2D.collider == null) {
                vertice = _origin+dir * ViewDistance;
            } else {
                vertice = raycastHit2D.point;
            }
            vertices[i] = vertice;
            angle -= AngleDecrease;
            if (i >= 2)
            {
                triangles[0 + triangleIndex] = 0;
                triangles[1 + triangleIndex] = i-1;
                triangles[2 + triangleIndex] = i;
                triangleIndex += 3;
            }
        }
        _mesh.vertices = vertices;
        _mesh.uv = uv;
        _mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }
}
```

And I check out the position of my object. It is right. All the variables are initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the flaw here is that you're making the mesh on the `MyField` script, but you're basing the points based on the parent GameObject.

If your parent GameObject is at <0,0>, then your mesh origin is at <0,0>. If your parent GameObject moves to <1,0>, then you're making your mesh origin at <1,0> **but your Mesh is local**. This means that you're actually setting your mesh to <1,0> + <1,0> = <2,0> in world coordinates.

Consider offsetting all your points instead:

```
void Update()
{
    _origin = _father.position;
    float angle = ViewAngle;
    float AngleDecrease = ViewAngle / RayCount;
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[RayCount + 2];
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
    int[] triangles = new int[3 * RayCount];
    //vertices[0]=_origin;
    vertices[0]=Vector3.zero;  // <------- THIS IS A CHANGE
    int triangleIndex = 0;
    Debug.Log(_origin);
    //draw mesh
    for (int i = 1; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)), Mathf.Sin(angle * (Mathf.PI / 180)),0);
        RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(_origin, dir, ViewDistance, LayerMask);
        Vector3 vertice;
        if (raycastHit2D.collider == null) {
            //vertice = _origin+dir * ViewDistance;
            vertice = dir * ViewDistance; // <---- THIS IS A CHANGE
        } else {
            //vertice = raycastHit2D.point;
            vertice = raycastHit2D.point - _origin; // <----- THIS IS A CHANGE
        }
        vertices[i] = vertice;
        angle -= AngleDecrease;
        if (i >= 2)
        {
            triangles[0 + triangleIndex] = 0;
            triangles[1 + triangleIndex] = i-1;
            triangles[2 + triangleIndex] = i;
            triangleIndex += 3;
        }
    }
    _mesh.vertices = vertices;
    _mesh.uv = uv;
    _mesh.triangles = triangles;
}
```

Just a few changes here. Again, I think your issue is that you're defining a local object (the `Mesh`) in world coordinates when it actually exists in local coordinates. The changes I'm proposing here shift the mesh to local coordinates.